# Looping Through className index not working...Alternatives?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, indexing

```
wins.push(document.getElementsByClassName("page")[x].attributes["id"].value);
```

This code is from a for() loop in JavaScript, using the variable 'x'. Unlike Google Chrome, FireFox and Opera don't seem to be comprehending the fact that the variable IS the index of the class that I wish to get the attribute "id" from.

Is there an alternative to this method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should work it out like this

```
function findPageclasses()
   {
     var Pageclasses= document.getElementsByClassName("page");
     for(var i=0; i<Pageclasses.length; i++)
        {
          wins.push(Pageclasses[i].attributes["id"].value);
        }
    }
```